# How can I go one level deeper in http json?

Tags: json, api, http, flutter

How can I unwrap my json of "data" *or* go one level deeper, so I can properly store it in Album Class?
Thanks in advance!

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "userId": 2,
        "title": "Lorem ipsum"
    }
}
```

Get Request:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:activity/models/Album.dart';

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://localhost:8000/album/1');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); // Values not assigned to Album
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Values not assigned because top level is "data" of json

```
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json.decode` to get `Map` 
and use this `Map` as parameter of `Album.fromJson` 
 
code snippet

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://localhost:8000/album/1');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      return Album.fromJson(responseData["data"]);      
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
```